# Forbidden Island

Tags: forbidden-island

We just played forbidden Island my partner was the pilot and we collected all four treasures and made it to the helicopter pad. Do we still need the  "helicopter Lift card" to fly off the island with the treasure seeing as they are the pilot anyways?

Also if I am a Navigator is it correct to say that I can move someone 2 spaces but not utilize that move for an action also . For example could I move someone 2 spaces (1 move)and then have them shore up a flooded tile ( turn # 2 of mine)?

Comment: You should split this up into two questions so that they can be better answered.

Comment: This question was split into [Navigator Role ability](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23383/navigator-role-ability) and [Helicopter Lift](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/23382/helicopter-lift), so it's now a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you still need to play Helicopter Lift to win the game, regardless of whether you have a pilot.

The Navigator is only able to move other players, not cause them to take actions.