# Helicopter Lift

Tags: forbidden-island

If I'm playing Forbidden island with a friend and we have all 4 treasures do we have to have the "Helicopter Lift " card still to leave the island from the launch pad if they are the pilot?

Answer (score 11):

Yes. "Fly to a tile" is not the same thing as "discard a Helicopter Lift card". Furthermore, the Pilot's ability specifically limits the flight to another island tile.

---

The win condition:

> Get to Fools’ Landing! Once you have collected all four treasures, everyone must move their pawns to the Fools’ Landing tile. Then, **one player must discard a Helicopter Lift card** to lift your team off of Forbidden Island for the win!

The Pilot's ability:

> Once per turn, **fly to any tile on the island** for 1 action.

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even if you have a Pilot, you must still play Helicopter Lift with everyone on the launch pad in order to win the game.