# Navigator Role ability

Tags: forbidden-island

If I am a Navigator and I decide to move my partner can I also assume an action through them also? For example if I move a partner 2 spaces beside a flooded tile can I shore up the piece for an action through them?

Answer (score 7):

The rules list four actions that a player can take on their turn:

> - Move
> - Shore Up
> - Give a Treasure Card
> - Capture a Treasure

Note that Move is an action and Shore Up is a different action.

The Navigator's card text says the following:

> Move another player up to 2 adjacent tiles for 1 action.

Since shoring up (or giving a treasure card, or capturing a treasure, or using a special ability that requires an action) is distinct from movement, **the Navigator is only permitted to make them do the Move action.** I imagine it would say something like "Have another player take 1 action for 1 of your actions" or something if it were allowed.

On the plus side, Navigators are useful for helping other players get in position, and they can move a character 2 tiles instead of the usual 1 that they would be doing on their turn.